# How to count the number of records/nodes in the xslt only whose value is greater than zero

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

My xml is as below :

```
<Report_Entry>
    <FileDateTime>2016-01-05T22:45:55.692-08:00</ FileDateTime>
    < CurrentYear>2016</ CurrentYear>
    < MemNum>133034</ MemNum>
    < SSN>000000</ SSN>
    < First_Name>Br</ First_Name>
    < Last_Name>G</ Last_Name>
    < Employee_Status_Date>2013-10-04-07:00</ Employee_Status_Date>
    < PayrollResults>
        < DepoDt>2016-01-08-08:00</ DepoDt>
        < FSA_Dep_Contributions>48.08</ FSA_Dep_Contributions>
        < FSA_Limitd_Contributions>0</ FSA_Limitd_Contributions>
        < FSA_Med_Contributions>0</ FSA_Med_Contributions>
    </ PayrollResults>
</ Report_Entry>
< Report_Entry>
    < FileDateTime>2016-01-05T22:45:55.692-08:00</ FileDateTime>
    < CurrentYear>2016</ CurrentYear>
    < MemNum>205767</ MemNum>
    < SSN>777777</ SSN>
    < First_Name>R</ First_Name>
    < Last_Name>Ks</ Last_Name>
    < PayrollResults>
        < DepoDt>2016-01-08-08:00</ DepoDt>
        < FSA_Dep_Contributions>0</ FSA_Dep_Contributions>
        < FSA_Limitd_Contributions>0</ FSA_Limitd_Contributions>
        < FSA_Med_Contributions>28.85</ FSA_Med_Contributions>
    </ PayrollResults>
</ Report_Entry>
```

My xslt is producing a text file and is counting the number of rows in the output file. The file in output rows will be produced only if any of the contribution is greater than zero from the above xml. I have used the below code but its outputting 3  whereas it should output only 2. Please let me know what am I doing worng in my code.

I am using this :

```
<xsl:variable name="recordCount">
  <xsl:value-of select=" 
    count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ PayrollResults[last()]/ FSA_Dep_Contributions != 0) +
    count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ PayrollResults[last()]/ FSA_Limitd_Contributions != 0) +
    count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ PayrollResults[last()]/ FSA_Med_Contributions != 0)"/> 
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($recordCount)"/>
```

Comment: I am using this code :<xsl:variable name="recordCount">
            <xsl:value-of select=" 
                count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ PayrollResults[last()]/ FSA_Dep_Contributions != 0) +
                count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ PayrollResults[last()]/ FSA_Limitd_Contributions != 0) +
                count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ PayrollResults[last()]/ FSA_Med_Contributions !=0 ) "/> 
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($recordCount,$spaces),1,10)"/>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your original expressions didn't work is because each expression returned a boolean. The `count()` of a boolean is always 1.

You could've changed `FSA_Med_Contributions != 0` to `FSA_Med_Contributions[. != 0]`

You probably could've also used `starts-with(local-name(),'FSA')` to condense all of the `count()` calls into 1.

Also, instead of `xsl:value-of`, use the `select` attribute when possible. This eliminates the need for the processor to create a new tree.

Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="recordCount" 
  select="count(Report_Data/Report_Entry/PayrollResults[last()]/*[starts-with(local-name(),'FSA') and . > 0])"/>
```

Note: There's no need to escape `>` as `&gt;` in XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

I used an online xpath evaluator to work it out, i have only used part of the count , you can apply the same to others this finds the count of FSA_Dep_Contributions having value greater than zero

```
 count(/Report_Data/Report_Entry/PayrollResults[last()]/FSA_Dep_Contributions[number(.) > 0 ])
```

If you are using xslt , you will have to change in xslt `>` to `&gt;`

Comment: Thanks , this solution worked. I am wondering why the expression count( Report_Data/ Report_Entry/ PayrollResults[last()]/ FSA_Dep_Contributions != 0) that I was using did not work. Why was the code I was using throwing the value 3 instead of 2.

Comment: It was just counting the number of the nodes, you need to convert values to numbers and use the comparison after that when using xpath or xslt.